# Removing non-standard (?id=) string from a wordpress landingpage url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a WordPress landing page using phpanywhere plugin to add some PHP scripts to the page.  The scripts populate various parts of the page with strings from a table in the db.  I pull the specific data using a query string in the url so the url looks like this: landingpage.com?id=12345. Now I need to pretty up the url for printed materials by getting rid of the query string like this: landingpage.com/12345.  I realize that there are several Q/A posted on the topic but I've tried the one's that seem to address this, and I just get page not found.  Here is my existing htaccess file contents.

```
# BEGIN WordPress

# END WordPress

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php56” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddType application/x-httpd-ea-php56 .php .php5 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Comment: What's your permalink structure?

Comment: Actually, I just realized that since it's a single page I could use "Plain".  Which of course removes all the content in htaccess between the WordPress tags

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^/(\d+) /index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

If you use the rewrite rule above, URLs like:

**landingpage.com/12345**

Will be internally rewritten to:

**landingpage.com?id=12345**

This rule needs to be placed above `# BEGIN WordPress` line.

PN: Make sure that `RewriteEngine On` is declared in your htaccess file before any rewrite rule occurrence.

Comment: Thanks, but that just gives me a 404. One thing different though,it gives me the Lightspeed 404 instead of the WordPress 404.

Comment: Yes, because WP has no rules in your htaccess file, hence no pretty URL handling, other than the one we want to enforce. Try `RewriteRule ^/?(\d+) /index.php?id=$1 [L]`

Comment: That gives me the same result

Comment: Did you *make sure* that `RewriteEngine On` is declared in your htaccess file *before* any rewrite rule occurrence?

Comment: yes [code]RewriteEngine On <line break>
RewriteRule ^/?(\d+) /index.php?id=$1 [L][/code]

Comment: Thanks for trying Eduardo...I appreciate your help!